# query the record of today's sales C# Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query when the user clicks the End Shift button to get the total sales of the day right away without entering the date

I can't figure out how can that be possible, I'm currently using this code for it, which he has to choose 2 dates.

I tried with 1 datetimepicker but I never get a result

can it be done without the user choosing the date?

```
 using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
        {

            conn.Open();
            string query = @"select SUM(SQuantity) AS 'Total' From Sales where Sdate = @datetime";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            textBox1.Text = @result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = @"select SUM(SQuantity) From Sales where Sdate = @datetime";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
```

> can it be done without the user choosing the date?

Yes, take a look at the @M.Rezaeyan answer.

Comment: Umm, writing user input directly into a SQL query? Ever heard of [SQL injection](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT - really? Injection in MS Access with C# client by DateTimePicker? It's sounds unbelievable.

Comment: Agree that injection is unlikely specifically with DateTimePicker; however it's very easy for the UI to change later on, while the insecure backend code will be inpatched. Direct use of user input to construct SQL queries is bad practice; instead of rationalizing a specific instance, it's much better to change the code to use parameters, which will always be secure.

Comment: @EugeneShvets-MSFT - you're definitely right. My words about impossibility injection was unadvisedly. Check it.

Comment: I don't know why, why actually it doesn't return any result

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT sum(SQuantity) as 'Total' FROM Sales WHERE Sdate = Date()
```

Final

```
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = @"select SUM(SQuantity) AS 'Total' From Sales where Sdate = Date()";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Are you shure that `CONVERT` function will be work in Access query?

Comment: you can use Date() instead of GETDATE() and Convert method.